# Invoking methods on a Q_GADGET stored in a QVariant

Tags: qt, qml

Using Qt 5.8, I have a `QAbstractListModel` derived class as the `model` of a QML `GridView`. The `model` defines a role called "object" that returns a `Q_GADGET` type defined thusly:

```
class MyObject {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(int count READ count CONSTANT)

public:
    int count() const;
    Q_INVOKABLE QString name(int idx) const;
};
```

Within my delegate I want to invoke `name`, as follows:

```
GridView {
    model: myModel
    delegate: Text {
        text: object.name(1)
    }
}
```

This results in an error:

> TypeError: Property 'name' of object MyObject(, , 2, 2) is
>   not a function

What is the correct way to get a construct like this to work?

Comment: Please provide more of QML code.

Comment: I updated the QML. It is a contrived example to get across my point.

Comment: I am almost certain that what you want is either `model.name(1)` or `model.modelData.name(1)` which could make correct reference but I cannot see much of that to conclude and even not sure if `myModel` was supplied.

Comment: `model.name(1)` would call a method on the `QAbstractListModel`, that's not what I want. `object` in this case is a data role, so it returns a `QVariant` that holds a `MyObject`. I can get the value of the `count` property, but I cannot call the method.

Comment: Huh, that is not `object` for QML? Make MyObject derived from QObject with Q_OBJECT macro then?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to use Q_GADGETs instead of Q_OBJECTs

Comment: Have you called `qRegisterMetaType()` for `MyObject`? If not, does that help? Does `text: object.count` do the expected thing?

Comment: Yes I've used `qRegisterMetaType` otherwise I wouldn't be able to return it as a `QVariant`. And yes, `object.count` does the expected thing.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: I have same problem too. `Q_PROPERTY` works, but `Q_INVOKABLE` not.